# Building A Global Object in Titanium to be written to sqlite3 database

Tags: sqlite, titanium, commonjs

This question is about implementation.
I'm building an android application with titanium.
There are multiple screens and i take data in each of them.
Each screen is a commonJS module

I want to write all the data i take to an sqlite3 database, but i suppose it would be inefficient to write them as i take inputs. Two ways come to my mind as to how to do this.

1. create an object and pass to each module to hold the data as i take them
2. create an object in the first module to hold the data and pass each data item to it by firing a custom event.

What i'm asking, is if there's a better approach to this or which of these two would be more efficient.

NB: I don't have a lot of screens, but that could change though.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think Ti.App.properties set and get string would do fine for you here is example too

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to store an object or array? and how would you do that?
The documentation is pretty sparse.

Comment: yes instead of string do list array and would do the trick for you

Answer (score 1):

Titanium.App.Properties are widely used for Global variable creation.

The following methods will help you to create global variable

1. [setBool](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setBool) : Sets the value of a property as a Boolean data type
2. [setDouble](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setDouble) : Sets the value of a property as a double (double-precision, floating point) data type
3. [setInt](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setInt) : Sets the value of a property as an integer data type
4. [setList](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setList) : Sets the value of a property as an array data type
5. [setObject](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setList) : Sets the value of a property as an object data type
6. [setString](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.App.Properties-method-setString) : Sets the value of a property as a string data type

All the above methods will allow user to save corresponding type of data as gloabl. You may retrieve saved values using `getBool, getDouble, getInt, getList, getObject, getString` methods respectively.